# Creating and pushing object to an array and getting "cannot read property ' ' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, undefined

I have these two object constructors and arrays:

```
//Houses
var houseArray = [];

//Generate street adress
var houseStreets = [..., ..., ...];

var generateAddress = function(){
    var index = round(random(0, houseStreets.length));
    var num = round(random(0, 9999));
    return num + " " + houseStreets[index];
};

// House constructor and prototypes
var House = function(address, x, y) {
    this.address = address;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

House.prototype.draw = function() {
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 30, 20);
    rectMode(CORNER);
};


//Households

var householdArray = [];

//Generate household names
var householdNames = [..., ..., ...];

var generateName = function(){
    var index = round(random(0, householdNames.length));
    return householdNames[index];
};

//Household constructor and prototypes
var Household = function(name, house) {
    this.name = name;
    this.house = house.address;
    this.x = house.x;
    this.y = house.y;
    this.isHomeOwner = true;
    this.isSelling = false;

};

Household.prototype.draw = function() {
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
};

Household.prototype.determinMove = function() {
    if(random(0, 100) <= 75){
        this.isSelling = true;
    }
};
```

In the initial phase of my simulation I create 20 households and 20 houses and the 20 households reside in the 20 houses:

```
// Populate initial houses
noFill();
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 15, 10));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 50, 10));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 85, 10));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 120, 10));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 155, 10));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 190, 10));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 225, 10));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 260, 10));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 295, 10));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 330, 10));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 15, 389));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 50, 389));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 85, 389));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 120, 389));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 155, 389));        
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 190, 389));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 225, 389));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 260, 389));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 295, 389));
houseArray.push(new House(generateAddress(), 330, 389));

//Populate initial households
for (var i = 0; i < houseArray.length; i++){
    householdArray.push(new Household(generateName(), houseArray[i]));
}
```

Now, I'm trying to build a function that will be called at the beginning of every new turn that will create 5 new households that do not reside anywhere (are not tied to a house in houseArray), and that have a random x (between 10 and 390) and random y (between 50 and 350) positions and I can't seem to make it work. Here is the code I came up with :

```
var newArrival = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    householdArray.push(new Household(generateName()));
    }
};
```

But when i do `print(householdArray[22].name)`I get a "cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error. Also I haven't figured out how to handle the random x and y positions yet.

**Questions: What is wrong with my code? What would be a good way to build a function that would create 5 new households in householdArray and that have a random x (between 10 and 390) and random y (between 50 and 350) positions?**

UPDATE: I believe that the problem is with the `Household` constructor. It would seem to not handle well the case where the `house` parameter is not fed an argument and I don't know how to fix that. In my `newArrival` function I do not feed a `house` parameter because there isn't one, the new arrivals do not yet have a house. That seems to be creating a problem. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Where is the debugger saying you are getting that error?  It should give you a filename and a line number.

Comment: Your code seems to be pushing only 5 items to `householdArray`. If that's the case, `householdArray[22]` will naturally return `undefined`.

Comment: @acdcjunior It may not be easy to see but in the initial setup I already generated 20 items in the `householdArray`. My `newArrival`function is meant to add 5 more.

Comment: @zero298 I'm coding it at Khanacademy. The "Oh Noes! guy" usually tells you where the problem is but in this case he doesn't. He just says  "cannot read property 'name' of undefined" when I do  a `println` on any index of the array. It's like my `newArrival`function somehow screws up the array. If I don't call the function, I'm able to `println` indexes 0 to 19 (the first 20 houselholds created at the beginning) but when I try to add some by calling the `newArrival` function, I can't access them anymore let alone the five new ones that should have been created at indexes 20 to 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed with the constructor. For some reason, which don't fully understand, I had to tell the constructor what to do in a case where the `house`parameter was not fed. Fixed it and everything works fine. Here is the code:

```
var Household = function(name, house) {
    if (house === undefined) {
        this.name = name;
        this.house = "HOMELESS";
        this.x = random(10, 390);
        this.y = random(50, 350);
        this.isHomeOwner = false;
        this.isSelling = false;
        this.askingPrice = 0;
    } else {
        this.name = name;
        this.house = house;
        this.x = house.x;
        this.y = house.y;
        this.isHomeOwner = true;
        this.isSelling = false;
        this.askingPrice = 0;
    }
};
```